# Replicate AFNetworking POST request with NSURLSession

Tags: swift, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

POST request with `AFNetworking`:

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/file.php"
let dictionary = ["key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [2,4,6]]

var error: NSError?
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)
let jsonString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let parameters = ["data" :  jsonString!]

let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
manager.POST(urlString, parameters: parameters, success:
    {
        requestOperation, response in

        let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        println(result)
    },
    failure:
    {
        requestOperation, error in
})
```

POST request with `NSURLSession`:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let bodyData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)!
request.HTTPBody = bodyData
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("\(bodyData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    println(result)
}).resume()
```

On server I have:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);
if (!$data) {
    echo "Error: Invalid POST data";
    return;
}
//do some stuff

echo "success";
```

On second case I get "Error: Invalid POST data". What I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding this: request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

Comment: @DanBeaulieu You would do that if the request wanted to let the server know that it would accept JSON response. But the response isn't the issue here. The problem is the request.

Comment: @rob thanks for clearing that up. I've been cheating with Alamofire until recently, so I'm new to NSUrl myself.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu - Using Alamofire isn't cheating. It's smart. Look at the clumsy (but necessary) code to percent escape below and you start to appreciate the value of these sorts of frameworks.

Comment: @Rob I agree, but I'd argue that it's smarter to understand how things work fundamentally before leaning on 3rd party libraries. I'll come full circle, back to Alamofire, I'm sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the AFNetworking example is not creating a JSON request whereas your `NSURLSession` example is. The AFNetworking example is creating a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request (where the value is a JSON string that you manually created). You can either change your server code to accept JSON requests or change the request to be a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request.

---

If you look at the AFNetworking request body in something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), you can see it generates something like:

```
data=%7B%22key1%22%3A%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%22key3%22%3A%5B%22Harold%20%26%20Maude%22%5D%2C%22key2%22%3A%5B2%2C4%2C6%5D%7D
```

If you un-percent-escape the value associated with `data`, that's effectively

```
data={"key1":[1,2,3],"key3":["Harold & Maude"],"key2":[2,4,6]}
```

(Note, I added the `key3` to show that the percent escaping is escaping standard reserved characters, plus `&` and `+`, too.)

If you want to do this yourself with `NSURLSession`, you'd have to build that and then percent escape it like so:

```
let allowed = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableCharacterSet
allowed.addCharactersInString("-._~")
let bodyString = "data=" + jsonString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowed)!
```

Frankly, this is pretty strange approach, embedding JSON within a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. I'd just change the server to accept a standard JSON request (bypassing `$_POST` variables altogether):

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

$body = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
```

By the way, once the server code accepts pure JSON request, the Swift 1.x client code would be:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)!
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    println(result)
}).resume()
```

AFNetworking equivalent would look like:

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/file.php"
let dictionary = ["key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [2,4,6]]

let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
manager.POST(urlString, parameters: parameters, success:
    {
        requestOperation, response in

        let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        println(result)
    },
    failure:
    {
        requestOperation, error in
})
```